# Is it possible to partially deserialise JSON into a struct in go?

Tags: json, go

I need to integrate with an API that returns loads of elements in its response.

Is it possible to cherry-pick just the fields I want with go's `json` library or do I need to deserialise the entire response?

Comment: If your code is too complicated to post, you need to construct an MCVE showcasing the example. Putting a bit more effort into your question is very likely to encourage others to put some effort into answering. Also, if your code is too complicated to make an MCVE, then it's probably really just poorly laid out (and presumably, impossible to unit test properly) so just the act of cleaning/writing an MCVE may really help you to answer i t. Otherwise, if the code isn't relevant, than neither is the note saying you're not including it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Here's an example of having 2 fields in json and only decoding one:

```
jsonString := `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`
var rec struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &rec)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("json.Unmarshal() failed with '%s'\n", err)
}
fmt.Printf("rec: %+v\n", rec)
```

When run it prints:

```
rec: {A:1}
```

i.e. field "a" in json was decoded and field "b" was discarded.

See https://play.golang.org/p/89tu-ZC4pR for full example.

Comment: That's really useful. Thanks.